# Dependency on libcgunwind.1.0.dylib

Tags: delphi, c++builder, delphi-10.2-tokyo, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

Is there a way to link the ***libcgunwind.1.0.dylib*** into the app that is compiled for MAC and not have a dependency? I want to be able to create a single console app that is not dependent on any dynamically loaded library. For windows application, we could uncheck the `"Link with Dynamic RTL"` and `"Link with runtime packages"` in project settings and that linked the `.Lib` and `.Bpi` files needed into the application, but those options do not exist for console applications.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
 By the way I am using `Delphi 10.2`.

Thank you
Sam

Comment: "*but those options do not exist for console applications*" - yes, they do, since the EXE still needs to use the packages in a static or dynamic manner.  Console app vs GUI app does not change that.  A `.dylib` is OSX's equivalent to a Windows `.DLL`. If you don't want to use a dynamic `.dylib` file than link to a static `.a` file instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I could not find the option in the project settings. Also I could not find a ***.a*** file for ***libcgunwind.1.0***.

Comment: If you don't have a static `.a` file, then you are out of luck, you are stuck using the `.dylib`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Based on all the reading I have done since this morning, ***libcgunwind.1.0.dylib*** is Embarcadero's invention used for unwinding the C exceptions in MAC. I was hoping they have provided a way for including a ***.a*** into the code instead of deploying the ***.dylib***.

Comment: I've reported this here: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-23769 (Please vote for it)

Comment: @JaredDavison I did vote for it, but it seems Embarcadero is not going to do anything about it till the 64 bit version of OSX is working.